# xampp interference with rails, django, other services

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, django, apache, xampp

I have been running Django and Rails on my Ubuntu Linux system for a while, and I recently had to install XAMPP/LAMPP because I have to do some local PHP development. Back when I used to use windows, when I installed XAMPP it messed up my Rails environment. Right now I am getting LAMPP to work, kinda, but instead of the splash page that is supposed to appear I get the "It Works" Apache default.

Other posts on this site mention that this is probably due to conflicting instances of the Apache server installed on my machine, and I should uninstall all php, mysql and apache programs I had before, and then reinstall xampp.

However, I don't want this to mess up my development for Rails/Django, will it? I'm very cautious because it has messed me up in the past.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no real way to know for sure if anything will be messed up, why dont you try installing LAMP using the native packages as they will have better support than XAMPP. http://gregrickaby.com/2011/05/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu-1104-natty.html

Since the Rails and Django development servers dont use port 80 then you should be fine installing Apache according to that guide.